Simplify an expression of radicals and rational functions to a form without denominators
To simplify the following expression in real variable $x$ (domain is $x\ge8$.)
$$y=\frac{(x-2)\sqrt x-(x+2)\sqrt{x-8}}{\sqrt[3]{x-\sqrt{(x-8) x}-4} \left(\sqrt x-\sqrt{x-8}\right)}$$
Calculating $y^3$,
I get $y=\sqrt[3]{\frac{1}{4}\bigl(x^2+20x-8-\sqrt{x(x-8)^3}\bigr)}$ for all $x\ge 8$.
I guess most of the time it is not possible to simplify a finite composition of radicals and rational functions to a form without denominators. Is there a more direct way to see if such an expression can be simplified to a form without denominators?
